# Getting error when trying to init NSArray with an Object?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a Save method that is supposed to save information entered in the text fields of a view controller.  The method properly saves this info inside the Class variables, but I want to save the object in an array.  When I try to do this , I get an error:

**Use of undeclared identifier 'homeworkAssignment'; did you mean '_homeworkAssignment'?**

Here is the save method

```
- (IBAction)Save:(UIButton *)sender {
self.homeworkAssignment = [[Homework alloc] init];
self.homeworkAssignment.className = self.ClassNameField.text;
self.homeworkAssignment.assignmentTitle = self.AssignmentTitleField.text;
self.homeworkAssignment.assignmentDiscription = self.DiscriptionTextView.text;
self.homeworkAssignment.pickerDate = self.DatePicker.date;

NSArray *MyHomeworkArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:homeworkAssignment, nil];
                                                           //Error here ^
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am able to set the homeworkAssignment object variables but get an error when trying to store the object in the array?

Comment: Do you know what `self.` means? Can you see the difference in how you are using `homeworkAssignment` on the lines which work and the one that doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `self.homeworkAssignment`.  That is the property you've already defined and have used on every other line in that method.

Answer (score 2):

Your previous references to `homeworkAssignment` was through the `homeworkAssignment` property. Eg:

`self.homeworkAssignment` is equal to `[self homeworkAssignment]`
`self.homeworkAssignment = something` is equal to `[self setHomeworkAssignment:something]`

As your property is auto synthesized, the ivar that backs is it has a leading underscore, eg `_homeworkAssignment`

Most of the time, you want to use the property to access the ivar, that is use `self.homeworkAssignment` or `[self homeworkAssignment]`. Notable exceptions are in your init and dealloc methods where you want to avoid any side effects of calling methods.